# PHP - Why can I print a private property here?

Tags: php, oop, properties, private

I have the following code. I have a `Human` class. The Human has properties, like `Eyes`, `Height`, etc.

Each property is not just a string, but an object, with a `protected` value. I assumed I wouldn't be able to access it unless a method belonging to that class returns or prints it. But it gets printed.

I understand that this issue could be exposed without this convolution, but I want to make sure how to handle this case in particular, too - in case I miss something.

```
class FilterObject {
 const FACIAL_FEATURES = ['eyes'];
}

class Property {
 protected $value;

 public function __construct($value) {
  $this->value = $value;
 }
 public function getValue() {
  return $this->value;
 }
}

class Eyes extends Property {
 const TYPE = 'eyes';
}

class Height extends Property {
 const TYPE = 'height';
}

class Human {
 protected $height;
 protected $wings;
 protected $eyes;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->height = new Height('2 metres');
  $this->eyes = new Eyes('blue');
 }

 public function describeFace() {
  $properties = get_object_vars($this);
  $properties = array_filter($properties);
  $properties = array_filter($properties, function($property){
   return in_array($property::TYPE, FilterObject::FACIAL_FEATURES);
  });
  print_r($properties);
 }
}

$john = new Human();
$john->describeFace();
```

This outputs:

```
Array ( [eyes] => Eyes Object ( [value:protected] => blue ) )
```

Why can I see the value Blue? Should I make sure it's not accessible? How do I do that?
Is this somehow because of `print_r`?

Comment: `print_r(), var_dump() and var_export() will also show protected and private properties of objects. Static class members will not be shown.` from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).... so don't use `print_r` in your code

Comment: I should have checked myself. Sorry and thanks. Do you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)....

> print_r(), var_dump() and var_export() will also show protected and private properties of objects. Static class members will not be shown.

print_r is basically a debugging function, so don't use it in your code